# Enable and disable textbox if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, textbox

I read this [article](http://jamesowers.co.uk/javascript/506/enabling-and-disabling-a-text-input-with-a-checkbox-using-jquery/) as suggested by an answer for a similar question. I did everything the article said, but the end result wasn't what I wanted.

I want the text box to be disabled by default. When the checkbox is checked, the textbox is enabled.

What happened was that the textbox is enabled by default, and when the checkbox is checked, the textbox is disabled.

Here is my code:

```
<td class="trow2">
    {$prefixselect}<input type="text" class="textbox" name="subject" size="40" maxlength="85" value="{$subject}" tabindex="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="input_control"  value="subject" />
    <strong>I believe {$forum['name']} is the best section for this topic.</strong>
</td>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.input_control').attr('checked', true);
        $('.input_control').click(function(){
            if($('input[name='+ $(this).attr('value')+']').attr('disabled') == false) {
                $('input[name='+ $(this).attr('value')+']').attr('disabled', true);
            }
            else {
                $('input[name='+ $(this).attr('value')+']').attr('disabled', false);    
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify your code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.input_control').change(function () {
        $('input[name=' + this.value + ']')[0].disabled = !this.checked;
    }).change();
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/t5qdvy9d/1/

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work for <textarea> at the same time?

Comment: i have same issues but i use radiobutton instead of checkbox. i have tried many thing but do not get why it is not woking.

Answer (score 1):

The checkbox and the input elements are siblings so you can use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.input_control').prop('checked', true);
    $('.input_control').change(function () {
        $(this).siblings('input').prop('disabled', this.checked)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery 1.6 or later, you can use this way. Of course, it works with the textarea element also. The demo below includes textarea element too.

edited: add textarea element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.input_control').change(function () {
        $(".textbox").prop('disabled', this.checked);
        $(".textarea").prop('disabled', this.checked);
    });
    $('.input_control').prop('checked', true);
    $('.input_control').trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="textbox" name="subject" size="40" maxlength="85" value="test subject" tabindex="1" />
<textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
<p></p>
<input type="checkbox" class="input_control"  value="subject" />
<strong>I believe forum name is the best section for this topic.</strong>
```