# PHP/HTML - Text box read only until check box clicked

Tags: php, html, web-applications

I have created a simple PHP form that searches a postgres table for a record that is related to an "RA" number and posts the corresponding data for that record on to the page. It looks something like this:

[image]

What I would like to do is add a check box next to each text field so that the displayed information is frozen/greyed out until the user clicks it, at which point I would like them to be able to edit the information.

Here's a snipped of the code so far:

```
<?php
$db = pg_connect("host=192.172.0.5 port=5432 dbname=ranumberdb user=user password=password");
$result = pg_query($db, "SELECT * FROM radio_program.radio_programs where rai_number = '$_POST[ranumber]'");
$row = pg_fetch_assoc($result);
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
echo "<ul>
   <form name='update' action='index.php' method='POST'>
    <li>RA Number:</li>
    <li><input type='text' name='ranumber_updated'
        value='$row[rai_number]' /></li>
    <li>Carrier Format:</li>
    <li><input type='text' name='carrier_format_updated'
        value='$row[carrier_format]' /></li>
    <li>Physical Location:</li>
    <li><input type='text' name='physical_location_updated'
        value='$row[physical_location]' /></li>
    <li>Brand Title:</li>
    <li><input type='text' name='brand_title_updated'
        value='$row[brand_title]' /></li>
    <li>Recording Artist:</li>
    <li><input type='text' name='recording_artist_updated'
        value='$row[recording_artist]' /></li>
    <li>Producer:</li>
    <li><input type='text' name='producer_updated'
        value='$row[producer]' /></li>
    <li>Session:</li>
    <li><input type='text' name='session_updated'
        value='$row[session]' /></li>
    <li>TX Date:</li>
    <li><input type='text' name='tx_date_updated'
        value='$row[tx_date]' /></li>
    <li>Network:</li>
    <li><input type='text' name='network_updated'
        value='$row[network]' /></li>
    <li>Programme Sub Category:</li>
    <li><input type='text' name='programme_sub_category_updated'
        value='$row[programme_sub_category]' /></li>
    <li>Programme Category:</li>
    <li><input type='text' name='programme_category_updated'
        value='$row[programme_category]' /></li>

?>
```

How can I add this functionality without massively changing what I have already done?

Cheers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable and disable textbox if checkbox is checked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760345/enable-and-disable-textbox-if-checkbox-is-checked)