# I am trying to enable the Quantity box when the check box is selected

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to enable the Quantity box when the checkbox is selected. Below is the HTML code and script I am calling

```html
<div class="spacechkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Product" id="Product" value="Cradlepoint 850"> 
    <label for="Product" class="productnamelabelname">Cradlepoint 850&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </label>
    <label for="quantity" class="productnamelabel">Quantity (between 1 and 5):</label>
    <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
</div>
<div class="spacechkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Product" _id="Product" value="Cradlepoint 850-1200M"> 
    <label for="Product" class="productnamelabelname">Cradlepoint 850-1200M</label>
    <label for="quantity" class="productnamelabel">Quantity (between 1 and 5):</label>
    <input type="number" _id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
</div>
<div class="spacechkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Product" _id="Product" value="Cradlepoint AER2200M"> 
    <label for="Product" class="productnamelabelname">Cradlepoint AER2200M</label>
    <label for="quantity" class="productnamelabel">Quantity (between 1 and 5):</label>
    <input type="number" _id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
</div>
```

```js
$("input[name='quantity']").prop('disabled', 'true');
$(".product").change(function(){
    $next = $(this).closest('div').find('[name=quantity]');
    $next.prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

But still, when accessing the page, no change is observed.

Comment: Please, if you care for your sanity, and the sanity of developers who work on your code after you, use CSS `padding` or `width`, not `&nbsp;` to increase the width of the `label`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable and disable textbox if checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760345/enable-and-disable-textbox-if-checkbox-is-checked)

Comment: Did my answer help you out?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for, but without the use of `next()`.

The reason `next()` wouldn't work in this case is if you check the last box, there is no `next`.

You were also not calling `product` correctly. You had the wrong text case (`Product` instead of `product`) and you were calling the class (`.`), not the id (`#`).

I've edited `_id` to be `id` and used a wildcard for any inputs that start with `product` so it will fire for all of them now.

I think radio buttons would have been a better choice in this example :)

```js
$( ":input[id^='product']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      
      $( ":input[id^='product']").prop('checked', false);
      $( ":input[id^='product']").prop('disabled', true);
      
      $(this).prop('checked', true);
      $(this).prop('disabled', false);
      
    } 
    
    if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
      $( ":input[id^='product']").prop('checked', false);
      $( ":input[id^='product']").prop('disabled', false);
    
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="product" id="product"> 
            <label for="product" class="productnamelabelname">Cradlepoint 850&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </label>
            <label for="quantity" class="productnamelabel">Quantity (between 1 and 5):</label>
            <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
            </div>
            <div class="spacechkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="product" id="product" value="Cradlepoint 850-1200M"> 
            <label for="product" class="productnamelabelname">Cradlepoint 850-1200M</label>
            <label for="quantity" class="productnamelabel">Quantity (between 1 and 5):</label>
            <input type="number" _id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
            </div>
            <div class="spacechkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="product" id="product" value="Cradlepoint AER2200M"> 
            <label for="product" class="productnamelabelname">Cradlepoint AER2200M</label>
            <label for="quantity" class="productnamelabel">Quantity (between 1 and 5):</label>
            <input type="number" _id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
            </div>
```